OU / GPO and Windows Defender Firewall - settings not permanent
I'm setting up an OU GPO for firewall and other settings for CIS SCA recommendations. I've run into a problem with the Firewall Settings. The PC's in the OU are getting all GPO configurations just as you would expect, and everything is working fine; However, After an unknown amount of time, a couple hours or next day, on the Domain Controller the OU's GPO settings for "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security Settings" are back to defaults, as if I had changed nothing - all other GPO setting are set as I had and staying.
So, the problem is with the domain controller, not the client included in the OU.
Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security
Settings:
State:

Turning on all 3 (Domain, Private, Public Firewall)
Block incoming (default)
Allow outgoing (default)

Settings:

Display notification = No
Rule Merging: Apply local firewall rules = No
Apply local connecton security rules = No

Logging

%SystemRoot%\System32\logfiles\firewall\domainfw.log (privatefw.log, and publicfw.log repectively)
SizeLimit 16,384
Log Dropped packets = Yes
Log successful connections

Note* Firewall are successfully writing to all 3 files.

Windows Server 2019, PC's are Dell Wyse ThinClients Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
NO other GPOs are there save Default Domain and Default Domain Controllers...

I'm stuck, any one seen this before or has suggestions?
Thank you for your time,

Hi, does you got another firewall / antivirus solution that can reset the native's windows solution ?

Oh no great point, simply windows Defender, fresh install of Windows, zero third party software

Then do a gpresult and valide nothing else apply, as the settings will not disappear that way. Check your local GPO too.

Yup thank you, the rsop gpresults say the proper GPO is the winning one. Everything is working on the client. The settings get applied as expected.
When i check tomorrow, the Windows Defender Firewall settings on the AD DC will have reverted to default

What does Group Policy Environment Debug logging show on the endpoint?

I found the answer, if you configure

Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security

then Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows Defender Firewall


Step 2) will change step 1).... Silly Microsoft, Silly me
thanks for all your help everyone.

Dell Wyse ThinClients Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC are configured to use Microsoft Unified Write Filter by default, make sure it's not on.
Such overlay is like deepfreeze, and will revert back any change done to the operating system.
Events related to overlay consumption are sent by UWF kernel mode components and are logged in the Windows Logs\System event log.
Make sure the service is not up and running, desactivate it in worst case to test out;

uwfmgr.exe filter disable


Yes, the write filter is disabled (red) for sure that's the first step for thin clients, I learned that one the hard way many, many times. LOL
